# Debug plug-in in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, stack-trace

I am trying to create a debug plug-in in eclipse. I need to get the exceptions thrown by the currently run program. Can anyone please help me to achieve this. The requirement is to get the entire exceptions, ie, the entire stack trace string. The problem currently is that the program already run contains errors and the exception may or may not be caught using try catch handlers. ie,the program containing error is out of our control. We need to extract the error caused by the already run program inside the plug in code. Can anyone give some suggestions.

Comment: @AleksandrM: that doesnt have an answer either

Comment: Can you be more specific ? The "program" that runs is a java application or an Eclipse plugin ?